# How to use self-defined variable in @require (Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript

In my script, there are many `@requires`. It looks like:

```
@require pathA/file1
@require pathA/file2
```

Sometimes I need to change `pathA`, after which it looks like this:

```
@require pathB/file1
@require pathB/file2
```

Is it possible to use a variable as follwoing:

```
PATH = pathA 
@require $PATH/file1
@require $PATH/file2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata block of a userscript (including its `@require`s) can't be changed after the script is loaded, but you *can* create a helper function that takes in script URLs and appends that script to the DOM:

```
const appendScript = url => new Promise(
  (resolve) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
);
const path = 'pathA'; // change this string when needed
Promise.all([
  appendScript(path + '/file1'),
  appendScript(path + '/file2')
])
  .then(() => {
    // everything is loaded
  });
```

Live snippet example, just so you can see the code working:

```js
const appendScript = url => new Promise(
  (resolve) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
);
const path = 'pathA'; // change this string when needed
Promise.all([
  appendScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js'),
  appendScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js')
])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('React is loaded!');
  });
```

Note that this will result in the script being loaded into the page, rather than into the sandbox, though that may well not be relevant for your case.

Comment: I can not have this worked. Is there any trick? Must I put all my code in between '//everything is loaded'?.     Or, is it possible to offer me a full runnable script so that I can run it by simply copy and paste?

Comment: It works fine for me, there's no trick or anything to it - see the Stack Snippet in the answer for a live demo, if you want. Yes, since the script loading is asynchronous, everything that depends on it should be inside the `.then`

Comment: It works now. But there is a problem. In my test, if the inserted link is some official js, there is no problem. But if I insert my lib, in which there is only one class with static methods, it seems not working. Do you have any ideal?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the code - can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: please see the context. It seems that I can not copy code into the comment. Notice that direct usage of require will make that work.

Comment: The problem is with the `https://gitlab.ps.nwcdcloud.cn/lhengyu/test/raw/master/test.js` site - it's not serving Javascript, it's serving that as `text/plain`, which the browser will refuse to execute for security reasons. See the error message: `Refused to execute script from 'https://gitlab.ps.nwcdcloud.cn/lhengyu/test/raw/master/test.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: Either ask them to fix it, or copy the code to your own site and serve it with the proper headers.